# Compare the text of two columns

Tags: sql

I’m working on this dataset to cleaning it
https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results, using Dremio (an online tool) so I can use an SQL editor (but i don't know what DBMS it use).

Now I’m trying to delete from the column Event the words that are contained in the column Sport. (I’ve already done some modification indeed in the column Event I’ve deleted the occurance of the words “man’s” and “women’s”).

Attached you’ll find

[The current situtation and the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvE14.png)

How can I solve the problem?

I hope I have been clear, Thank you in advance for help. :)

Edit: I've found the original query made by Dremio

```
SELECT ID, Name, Gender, Age, Height, Weight, Team, "Olympic Games"."Year" AS "Year", Season, City, Sport, CASE WHEN regexp_like(CASE WHEN regexp_like(Event, '.*?\QMen''s\E.*?') THEN regexp_replace(Event, '\QMen''s\E', '') ELSE Event END, '.*?\QWomen''s\E.*?') THEN regexp_replace(CASE WHEN regexp_like(Event, '.*?\QMen''s\E.*?') THEN regexp_replace(Event, '\QMen''s\E', '') ELSE Event END, '\QWomen''s\E', '') ELSE CASE WHEN regexp_like(Event, '.*?\QMen''s\E.*?') THEN regexp_replace(Event, '\QMen''s\E', '') ELSE Event END END AS Event, Medal
FROM "@Sboorn"."Olympic Games"
 WHERE NOT regexp_like(ID, '.*?\QID\E.*?')
```

Comment: What is the current query you are using? Can you edit the post and add it?

Comment: I'm not using any queries so far, i don't know how to make it to get the desired result

Comment: I've modified the post with the original query made by Dremio, I think that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` to heck if `event` starts with the `sport` and a space. If so use `substring()` to omit the first *n* characters for *n* the length of `sport` and the space. Else return `event` unchanged.

```
SELECT sport,
       CASE
         WHEN event LIKE concatenate(sport, ' %') THEN
           substring(event, length(sport) + 2, length(event) - length(sport) - 1) 
         ELSE
           event
       END event
       FROM elbat;
```

As you didn't tag your actual DBMS, the names of the functions might differ (e.g. `concat()` instead of `concatenate()`, `substr()` instead of `substring()` or `len()` instead of `length()`). But some equivalent should be available in most DBMS.

Depending on the actual DBMS there also might be more elegant solutions, like regular expressions.

And next time please don't post images. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements to show how your tables look like and plain text to show the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, i didn't specified the DBMS because i'm using Dremio and i don't know what it use. 
However i've modified the post with the original query made by Dremio and i'm trying to adapt the proposed solution